# ASP.NET-5 with EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

Is it possible to use the new ASP.NET with Entity Framework 6 instead of Entity Framework v7?

I use the latest Visual Studio 2015 and could not add a Ado.Net Data Model but the Reference to EF6 was added.

Comment: Can't you mannually download & install it using nuget package console?

Comment: Un-install EF7 though nuggets. then run "Install-Package EntityFramework -version 6.1.2" though nugget console.

Comment: Doesn't work. I used "Uninstall-Package EntityFramework" and then "Install-Package EntityFramework -version 6.1.2". In the project.json are under dependencies are the EntityFramework  6.1.2 but there is no Element like ado.net DataModel.

Comment: did you get an error or install went fine?

Comment: no, nuget package install running without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Most existing packages, such as EF6, will not support asp.net Core 5; because of the significant differences, they need to be manually updated. If you're wanting to use EF6 you'll need to stick to asp.net 5 (not Core).

I've run into a series of issues running the EF6 package manager commands, such as `Add-Migration`, in VS2015 CTP6; I believe they're still working on updates. I was able to get them working in a .Net 4.5 library that is referenced by my .Net 5 libraries, but I've found that occasionally I have to uninstall and install EF6 again to get the package manager commands working.